# Beginner Java: How to write a method to set a variable to 0?

Tags: java

I need to create a Format method (within a class called USBDrive) which resets the capacity of a USBDrive to zero in Java.  Any suggestions please?

Comment: `which resets the capacity of a USBDrive to zero in Java` explain this please

Comment: he wants to format the drive, as the name says. Perhaps he'll also be happy with erasing all files.

Comment: This question needs way more details lest it be closed.

Comment: @S.P.Floyd - seanizer  but how it will reset capacity if he format it

Comment: Formatting could change the file system type, if you are not careful. Or format the wrong drive if you have a bug/configuration issue.

Comment: hi, I simply want to format the drive, deleting all contents and reset the capacity to zero.  it's part of a past exam paper i'm completing as revision prior to an exam.

Comment: simply? that's low level stuff and not at all simple in java

Comment: thanks for getting back to me so quickly. maybe i'm not explaining it properly but it's part of a past paper 2nd year java exam, i wasn't expecting to create this much consternation!

Comment: @Lewis: It's creating this much "consternation" because you're failing to describe your problem properly! If it's that early in the course, it's likely that USBDrive is just something that looks like a USBDrive but doesn't interface with an actual physical USB drive. Am I correct? You should really mention these things.

Comment: ok, first off i appreciate you all trying to help me, here's what i have - a class called USBDrive with three attributes - Make, Capacity and Price and Acceessor/Mutator methods for all three.  the final part of the question is to create and i'm going to quote directly "a Format method, which resets the capacity of the USBDrive to zero anda toString method, which will present the output of a USBDrive object in a user friendly manner".  i've done it all apart from the Format method...  does that make it any clearer?  thanks.  lewis

Comment: Well, forgive me if I'm slow, but if format did "reset capacity to zero" then no more data could be written there. Wouldn't it have to reset capacity to maximum for that device?

Comment: Are you sure, you should really format the drive? If it's an assignment, then you should make a class for USBDrive with a few methods and a few variables, for example capacity, file list, etc. then when you want to invoke format form your class, you should set capacity variable to 0... I'm not sure, but I think you'll never been asked to implement those features using java in an assignment.

Comment: that's quite true but that's a direct quote - i assume what it's meant to mean is that there are zero files on the drive after format...

Comment: @Lewis: Well, then if I were you, I'd just delete all files and folders on the USB drive.

Comment: Why don't you post the USBDrive class? It kind of sounds like you're not at all dealing with an actual USB drive, which completely changes the way most people are looking at this question.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing:

If you just want to erase all files on the disk, use a method like this:

```
public static void eraseRecursively(final File dir, final boolean eraseDir){
    for(final File item : dir.listFiles()){
        if(item.isDirectory()){
            eraseRecursively(item, true);
        } else{
            item.delete();
        }
    }
    if(eraseDir){
        dir.delete();
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
eraseRecursively(
    yourUsbRootDir,
    false /* if true, it will try to delete the root dir */
);
```

If you want to really format the disk, there's no way you can do that from Java, you will have to launch an external process.

Answer (score 0):

If you're formatting the drive, won't you want to set the capacity to the size of the drive (not 0)?

Formatting the drive will depend a great deal on what format you want to use.  FAT? FAT32? ext[234]? NTFS?  Your own custom format?  Regardless, you'll need some way to access the USB device directly, using the UMS (USB Mass Storage) [protocol](http://www.usb.org/developers/devclass_docs/usb-msc-overview-1.3b.pdf).

Good luck!